# Webbrowser Trying to parse some page which uses ajax to load data

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, browser

I am trying to parse some images from this site..
I was using htmlagilitypack for the other pages
but this page uses ajax to load images

so this is how the webpage works.

1. has a div tag including nothing.
2. right below the div they have a script tag in cdata thing

   ```
   <script type="text/javscript> //<
   ![CDATA[ (function(){

   ajax POST request to a 'aaaaaa.js' file with the id parameter and if the request is success, it updates the blank div my changing the innerHTML value.
   })(); //]]> 
   </script>
   ```

So.. what I tried was...

1. navigate to that page using the webbrowser control.
   which loads the image just fine but when I try to get the value of 'DocumentText'
   it only shows the blank div tag...
2. try to get straight data from the ajax POST using webrequest and webresponse..
   but.. maybe cause its .js file.. it doesnt work.. I only get http errors.
3. Browse right to the js file with the parameters attached.
   gives me an error page
4. Browse the page Im trying to parse and then navigate to the .js page.
   (I guess the browser caches something when i browse the original page.. but i dont know what it is.)
   I do get the json response! i can use this data.. but since the webbrowser control is using IE. It just asks me if i want to download the responsed js file.

Comment: What is the site address?  When you load the page via WebBrowser control and the DocumentText property is empty, can you get the image via the DOM (eg.  WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img") ) ?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#/" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @John Saunders Sorry! It was my first time writing

Comment: @Boo Well its an Korean site. http://cartoon.media.daum.net/webtoon/viewer/15730 this is one of the pages. And the way u suggested works! But I'm trying to figure out a better cleaner way.. I've tried a way of getting the value of webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml and work with HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument. If I cant find a direct way of accessing the ajax request and response part, i guess i will stick to this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So theres the method of using the DOM I mentioned in my comment.

Another method could be to use FiddlerCore  ( http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/)

Or make the ajax call yourself.  You will have to make sure you respect cookies, redirects, and all the headers.